# Several changes in storyboard file after updating from iOS 7 to iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a couple of storyboard files. I noticed changes every time I would just touch the file but that was normal behavior. However, recently, I updated my Xcode to Xcode 6.1 with iOS 8.1 support. I did not make any changes to the storyboard files. But I see a whole lot of changes, mainly

- Removal of simulatedOrientationMetrics
- Removal of autoresizingMasks
- Changes in UI elements' sizes and sometimes frames
- Renaming components

Eg:

`<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>` has been removed.

`<deployment identifier="iOS"/>` has been added.

`<simulatedOrientationMetrics key="simulatedOrientationMetrics" orientation="landscapeRight"/>` has been removed.

`<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="852"/>` has been modified to `<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="308" height="1024"/>`.

`<!--Example Table View Controller - Example-->` has been modified to `<!--Example-->`

Is anybody else seeing similar changes? If so, why have they been changed?

Comment: I had been experiencing the same. Removal of Autoresizing mask was a killer.

Comment: `<deployment identifier="iOS"/>` was being removed whenever i open xcode and my project is version controlled so this is really annoying